# What is the best way to configure a bean override of MongoDatastore class in a Grails application that use GORM mongoDB plugin?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

In a standard Grails Application that use GORM MongoDB plugin, if you override the class MongoDatastore  with a new one (for adding some custom behaviour) eg:

```
class MyMongoDatastore extends MongoDatastore{ 

      here the override methods and property

}
```

and you want to configure it to be used by plugin, what's the best approach to use?

Answer (score 0):

In `resources.groovy` define the bean you're overriding and the class your overriding with:

```
beans = {
    mongoDatastore(MyMongoDatastore)
}
```

https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/spring.html

I've not used mongo before - assuming those names are correct given your example.

Comment: Hi Erich, this doesn't work cause of MongoDatastore have different constructors, no one with no arguments.So the initialization of it will depend on some vary options. I don't find any way to to that  in  resource.groovy

Comment: Hi Giuseppe Iacobucci, 

Did you make it work? I also want to override a bean which is part of dependent jar file. When I define that bean with overridden class.. it fails as the parent class does not have no-org constructor.. Thanks.